# I'm having problem to create a list with for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I would like to have 10 results in my code, but I'm receiving just one.

I'm trying to have the variable "number" acting like 1, 2, 3... 10, and receive 10 results, but I receive just one.

that is what I tried so far:

```
one_to_ten <- c(1:10) for (number in one_to_ten) {
     fluxo_div_primeiro <- c(0.68*((1+0.02)^number))
}
fluxo_div_primeiro
```

The actual result is only 0.82916, but the expected result would be:

```
#0.6936,    0.707472, 0.72162144, 0.736053869, 0.750774946, 0.765790445,     
#0.781106254,   0.796728379,    0.812662947 0.828916206
```

Comment: Please, write your question in a way that we can understand what are you seeking, in a very clear way. Then explain what are you doing and what are you expecting. Improve your title pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that in each run of the loop, the object is getting updated/replaced by the new output.  Instead, we initialize an output vector of the same size and then update each of the elements with the index 'number'.  Usuallly, if it is not a sequence, loop through the sequence of number, but here it is in sequence i.e from 1 through 10.

```
fluxo_div_primeiro <- numeric(10)
one_to_ten <- c(1:10) 
for (number in one_to_ten) {
   fluxo_div_primeiro[number] <- 0.68*((1+0.02)^number)
   }
fluxo_div_primeiro
#[1] 0.6936000 0.7074720 0.7216214 0.7360539 0.7507749 0.7657904 
#[7] 0.7811063 0.7967284 0.8126629 0.8289162
```

---

Another option is to intialize with a bare vector

```
fluxo_div_primeiro <- c()
```

and then update the vector by concatenating the values with the original vector

```
for (number in one_to_ten) {
   fluxo_div_primeiro <- c(fluxo_div_primeiro, 0.68*((1+0.02)^number))
   }
fluxo_div_primeiro
#[1] 0.6936000 0.7074720 0.7216214 0.7360539 0.7507749 0.7657904 
#[7] 0.7811063 0.7967284 0.8126629 0.8289162
```

---

Note that these are vectorized.  So, we don't need any loop

```
(0.68 * (1 + 0.02) ^ (1:10))
#[1] 0.6936000 0.7074720 0.7216214 0.7360539 0.7507749 0.7657904 
#[7] 0.7811063 0.7967284 0.8126629 0.8289162
```

Answer (score 0):

fluxo_div_primeiro
Keep about variable inside the loop